# How to remove com.jackson.databind packages from the ehcache-2.10.6.jar

Tags: java, gradle, jar, jackson, gradle-shadow-plugin

We have ehcache-2.10.6.jar jar in our dependecies. It contains com.jackson.databind package that has marked as vulnerable by Trivy. No ehcache versions have non-vulnerable com.jackson.databind.

How we can shade or repackage the jar to make it missing com.jackson.databind package?

Shading or exclusion doesn't help:

```
shadowJar {
    zip64 true
    dependencies {
        exclude(dependency("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.6"))
    }

    relocate 'com.fasterxml.jackson', 'shadow.com.fasterxml.jackson'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of excluding that package, use the line below to resolve the vulnerability-

```
group: 'net.sf.ehcache.internal', name: 'ehcache-core', version: '2.10.6'
```

Repository url - https://repo.terracotta.org/maven2/

Comment: I am using hibernate-ehcache.5.6.9.Final jar . ehcache-2.10.6 is it's dependency. How can I remove the this jackson-databind vulnerability from it?